# moving changed files to another branch for check-in

Tags: git

This often happens to me: I write some code, go to check in my changes, and then realize I'm not in the proper branch to check in those changes. However I can't switch to another branch without my changes reverting. Is there a way to move changes to another branch to be checked in there?

Answer (score 1158, accepted):

### Updated Answer

No need to use `stash` command. uncommitted changes do not belong to any branch so just use `git checkout -b <new-branch>`

---

### Orginal Answer

`git stash` is your friend.

If you have not made the commit yet, just run `git stash`. This will save away all of your changes.

Switch to the branch you want the changes on and run `git stash pop`.

There are lots of uses for git stash. This is certainly one of the more useful reasons.

An example:

```
# work on some code
git stash
git checkout correct-branch
git stash pop
```

Comment: No need to stash uncommitted changed, they go with you when you check out a branch.  Stash is more for longer term storage of temporary things (stuff you want to finish and commit later, but you need to do something else right now).

Comment: I get this. So I have to stash, switch branch and then pop

`C:\kf [develop +0 ~4 -0]> git checkout feature/customers<br/>
    error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:<br/>
            AspWebApp.vNext/global.asa<br/>
            RestApi/Web.config<br/>
    Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.<br/>
    Aborting`

Comment: @Tekkub "longer term storage of temporary things" that saying feels very awkward, another point to use stash is it pushes it in a stack so if you don't want it to carry over and work on something else it is useful in that way. Yes you don't have to but just feels cleaner and more in control.

Comment: bravo baby! should append what you should do if you made the commits

Comment: Using stash has one big disadvantage. If you must merge after the stash pop, then the diffs are a mess: LOCAL and REMOTE are mixed up; at least with Git Extensions and Perforce P4Merge. REMOTE or Theirs is your stash and LOCAL or Ours is someone elses code from the branch. Do you still get it? So I prefer Amber's approach.

Comment: @bill You are awesome.  This worked like a charm.  Of course I didn't have very many edits before I discovered that I was on wrong branch.  Life-saver.

Comment: @Tekkub That is only true if the branch you are switching to is up to date with the branch you are on. If for example you are accidentally working on prod branch and need to switch to stage branch but stage has changed in the mean-time stash is the only way to make the switch.

Comment: @Tekkub the real answer's in the comments ;)

Comment: Instead of using `git stash pop`, it's safer to use `git stash apply` and when all the changes are applied to your desired branch, then you could run `git stash drop` to drop stash. This helps you to not lose changes when there are merge conflicts. If you use `git stash pop`, you might end up losing some changes in case of conflicts.

Comment: _"...you might end up losing some changes in case of conflicts"_
**No comments on this??!** @Atherion, I agree `stash` seems like a good command workflow.

Comment: Your last comment is not correct. If I want my changes to depend on my main branch, I need to first be able to switch to that branch. Otherwise it causes all sorts of other issues and changing the branch a branch depends on has not worked for me. The stash-ing works, though. Great!

Answer (score 325):

**If you haven't already committed your changes**, just use `git checkout` to move to the new branch and then commit them normally - changes to files are not tied to a particular branch until you commit them.

If you **have** already committed your changes:

1. Type `git log` and remember the SHA of the commit you want to move.
2. Check out the branch you want to move the commit to.
3. Type `git cherry-pick SHA` substituting the SHA from above.
4. Switch back to your original branch.
5. Use `git reset HEAD~1` to reset back before your wrong-branch commit.

`cherry-pick` takes a given commit and applies it to the currently checked-out head, thus allowing you to copy the commit over to a new branch.

Comment: You shouldn't even need to cherry-pick here.  `git reset HEAD~N --soft` and then `git checkout -b` to move all the _now_ uncommitted code to a new branch.

Comment: **changes to files are not tied to a particular branch until you commit them.** <-- this. This solved a mystery for me. Thanks.

Comment: I get the following error when trying to switch branches: "local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout". So, it doesn't seem like I can move to a different branch and commit normally.

Comment: @Mischa it does not work if you are switching between two branches that have different histories

Comment: @Aaron that's much nicer (for the post-commit scenario)! Please make a separate answer.

Comment: But in my case I can't change the branch it aborts, ask to do something about changed files 
"error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:"

Answer (score 23):

Sadly this happens to me quite regularly as well and I use `git stash` if I realized my mistake before `git commit` and use `git cherry-pick` otherwise, both commands are explained pretty well in other answers

I want to add a clarification for `git checkout targetBranch`: **this command will only preserve your working directory and staged snapshot if targetBranch has the same history as your current branch**

> If you haven't already committed your changes, just use git checkout
>   to move to the *new branch* and then commit them normally

@Amber's statement is not false, when you move to a **newBranch**,`git checkout -b newBranch`, a new pointer is created and it is pointing to the exact same commit as your current branch.
In fact, if you happened to have an another branch that shares history with your current branch (both point at the same commit) you can "move your changes" by `git checkout targetBranch`

However, usually different branches means different history, and Git will not allow you to switch between these branches with a dirty working directory or staging area. in which case you can either do `git checkout -f targetBranch` (clean and throwaway changes) or `git stage` + `git checkout targetBranch` (clean and **save** changes), simply running `git checkout targetBranch` will give an error:

> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten
>   by checkout:
>           ...
>   Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches. Aborting

Answer (score 11):

A **soft git reset** will put committed changes back into your index. Next, checkout the branch you had intended to commit on. Then *git commit* with a new commit message.

1. `git reset --soft <commit>`
2. `git checkout <branch>`
3. `git commit -m "Commit message goes here"`

From [git docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset):

> `git reset [<mode>] [<commit>]` This form resets the current branch head
>   to  and possibly updates the index (resetting it to the tree
>   of ) and the working tree depending on . If  is
>   omitted, defaults to --mixed. The  must be one of the following:
>
> `--soft` Does not touch the index file or the working tree at all (but resets the head to , just like all modes do). This leaves all
>   your changed files "Changes to be committed", as git status would put
>   it.

Comment: As others pointed out before, this will only work if the two branches you're switching from/to have identical history.

Answer (score 0):

If you created new files you can do this:

```sh
git checkout main
git checkout -b branch-b
git checkout branch-a :rel/path/to/yourchangedfiles
git commit -m "w"
git checkout branch-a

git checkout main :rel/path/to/yourchangedfiles

# if this happens:
error: pathspec ':rel/path/to/yourchangedfiles' did not match any file(s) known to git

# then just rm the folder
trash-put rel/path/to/yourchangedfiles
```