# Git - Save non-committed changes to a different branch

Tags: git

I recently switched to my `master` branch so I could get the latest updates. While in the 'master' branch I did some work and made changes that I would like to apply to a different `feature` branch. However, I don't want to commit these changes to the `master` branch yet. Is there a way with Git that I could apply these changes to a different `feature` branch without first committing them to the `master` branch. I also don't want to lose the changes.

Comment: Please read [ask] and try searching before asking a new question. You're looking to "stash" your changes.

Comment: See also [moving changed files to another branch for check-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217894/moving-changed-files-to-another-branch-for-check-in) and many others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git stash` has you covered!

1. While in the master branch, with the uncommitted files, run `git stash`.
2. Switch to your feature branch
3. Run `git stash apply`

---

`git stash` will save your uncommited changes into a "stash".

`git stash apply` will apply the latest stash.

If you have more than one stash, you can list them by running `git stash list`

Read more here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash

Comment: Thanks ... I did not realize `stash` worked between branches

Answer (score 1):

May not be the nicest way to do this, but I would commit the changes to master, but DON'T PUSH.  Then switch to your feature branch and merge the changes into the feature branch.  Then, switch back to master and checkout the previous commit that doesn't include the changes.